# What does "va a lo que va" mean?

Tags: vocabulario, significado

2 examples:

> Hay una pelirroja, que yo sé que va de lo que va porque me busca, eso se nota.

> La ciencia va a lo que va y no se ocupa de eventuales conflictos entre hechos demostrados experimentalmente y la religión.

Comment: Your question says "Va a lo que va" and your first sentence says: va de lo que va". The second one: va a lo que va would be said in English: Science does what it has to do or does as it does.

Answer (score 3):

It just means that they "go after what they go after", i.e. that they "have their own goals". The phrase is used when those goals are clear or obvious:

- There is a red-headed girl, and it is clear what she is after, because she always looks for me, one notices these things.
- Science has its own goals, and it does not address possible conflicts between experimentally demonstrated facts and religion.

Answer (score 1):

1. I know what her intentions are (showing up to get someone's attention)
2. You should stick to what you know best (in your field of expertise)(pruebas empíricas)

Answer (score 0):

*Que tal?*

- La expresión "*va a lo que va*", es una forma coloquial que indica dirección, verbo "*ir*", dirigirse a... Por tanto significa que la persona, la institución, una ciencia, una política... se dirige hacia aquello que le interesa de manera muy especifica por algo en concreto y en cada momento determinado.
  Espero te haya ayudado. Diego.